# How to sort a List with LINQ using Nested Property

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a Json file with following data:

```
[ 
   { "Id": 510, "Title": "Big Start", "Author": [{ "AuthId": 7777, "Name": "Tom" }] },
   { "Id": 511, "Title": "Rising Tide", "Author": [{ "AuthId": 6666, "Name": "Bob" }] }
]
```

For the above, I have defined the following classes:

```
public class Book {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public List<Author> Authors { get; set; }
 }
    
 public class Author {
  public int AuthId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

I have deserialized the json data using the following code:

```
List<Book> books;
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("...")))
 {
  books = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(sr.ReadToEnd()).ToList()
 }
```

Now I want to sort the list of books using author Name. I have tried the following:

```
var list = books.OrderBy(b => b.Author.OrderBy(a => a.Name)).ToList();
```

But I get the error message 'At least one object must implement IComparable'.

Can someone help me sort the above list using the **nested author Name**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my case, there will always be one author in the list. So looking at the above json data, record with Id 511 will be listed before 510 since 'Bob' comes before 'Tom'. I hope this clarifies. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thing is, Authors is a List, so which author name do we sort by? There might be many. "Book1, by Alfred and Zeus", "Book2 by Zigo, Mary and Ada" - how do these books sort? How do they sort if Book2 was by Ada, Mary and Zigo?

If there's only ever one author it's fairly simple

```
var list = books.OrderBy(b => b.Authors.First().Name).ToList();
```

As authors is a list you could also index it

```
var list = books.OrderBy(b => b.Authors[0].Name).ToList();
```

If there is ever more than one author you need to have a think about which author is used for sort.. If multiple authors contribute as tie breakers it gets more complex.. You could end up with a ThenBy that skips the first author etc, but then you need to consider if you're going to sort the authors too..

Remember that c# is case sens, so "bob" will sort after "Tom" and also the code above won't work if here are zero authors - you've implied there will always be one but if not, consider `FirstOrDefault()?.Name??""` ..

..sometimes the simplest of questions leads to the most involved set of work! ;)

Comment: Genius. Worked like a charm. Thank you so very much.

Comment: Thanks for the additional tip, FirstOrDefault() for 0 authors. That makes it even more clear.